# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then does $(q+1)/2 \mid \sigma(n^2)$ hold?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(M)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $M$.  If $N$ is odd and $\sigma(N)=2N$, then $N$ is called an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Euler showed that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must have the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since $q$ is prime and $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have the divisibility constraint
$$q+1 = \sigma(q) \mid \sigma(q^k)  \mid \sigma(N) = 2N$$
from which it follows that $(q+1)/2 \mid N = q^k n^2$, which implies that $(q+1)/2 \mid n^2$.

Likewise, since $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$, then it can be shown that
$$q \mid q^k \mid \sigma(n^2).$$

Here is my question:

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then does $(q+1)/2 \mid \sigma(n^2)$ hold?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.

Assume to the contrary that $(q+1)/2 \mid \sigma(n^2)$.  Since $(q+1)/2 \mid n^2$, this assumption implies that
$$\frac{q+1}{2} \mid \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$

It is known that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}=\frac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)),$$
where $D(x) = 2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) and $s(x) = \sigma(x)-x$ is the [sum of the aliquot divisors](http://oeis.org/A001065) of the positive integer $x$.

Alas, this is where I get stuck.

Comment: If $k=1$, then $N$ takes the form
$$N = \frac{q(q+1)}{2}\cdot{D(n^2)}.$$
If $k>1$, then $N$ takes the form
$$N = \frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{\frac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)}}.$$
(**Reference: [Conditions equivalent to the Descartes–Frenicle–Sorli Conjecture on odd perfect numbers](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf)**, page 19)